# Internet Explorer Images Width and @font-face issues

Tags: html, internet-explorer, font-face

Ok, I'm having issues with IE and width values of 25% set on images.  How can I fix this?

Image of what IE 9 looks like below:

[image: IE9 Display Bug!]

Here is an image of what it is supposed to look like, and how it looks in all other browsers:  (Chrome, Opera, Firefox, Safari):

[image: How the Images are supposed to be!]

The Code I am using for this is as follows...

***HTML***:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>2013 Conference Test Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    </head>
<body>

<div class="header">
    <div style="width: 100%;">
        <img class='header_img' src='images/image1.jpg' />
        <img class='header_img' src='images/image2.jpg' />
        <img class='header_img' src='images/image3.jpg' />
        <img class='header_img' src='images/image4.jpg' />
    </div>
    <div class="header_text big_text"><div>SAVE THE DATE!</div><div style="margin-top: -.2em;">2013 OFN CONFERENCE</div>
    </div>
    <div class="header_text" style="margin-top: -.2em;">
        <p class="medium_text"><span style="padding-right: 15px;">October 15-18, 2013</span> &bull; <span style="padding-left: 15px;">Philadelphia, PA</span>
    </div>
    <div class="header_text">
        <p style="padding: 0px 10% 1.5em; line-height: 1.5em;">Join us for this year's conference at the Philadelphia Marriot Downtown, just steps away from historic sites, great cultural destinations, and Opportunity Finance Network's own headquarters!  Registration opens in August, 2013.</p>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

***CSS***:

```
html,body
{
    margin:0 0 0 0;
    padding:0 0 0 0;
}

.header
{
    background-color: #049EAB;
    width: 100%;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: hnc_font;
    src: url('../fonts/hnc.eot');
    src: local('hnc_font'), url('../fonts/hnc.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/hnc.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/hnc.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
}

.header_img
{
    width:25%;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
}

.header_text
{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

.medium_text
{
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-family: hnc_font;
}

p
{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, Tahoma;
}

.big_text
{
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px black;
    font-size: 5.5em;
    font-family: hnc_font;
}
```

Problems detected:

1. The 4 Images at the top are not stretching to the width of the screen.  TBH, this is extremely odd behavior that the images are resizing down.  It seems that they are resizing down by 25% of the previous image each time it gets displayed, instead of the screen's width.  ODD!
2. The embedding of a font in CSS using @font-face is not even working here in IE.  The font is a Helvetica derivative style font.  Looks exactly the way it should in the 2nd pic, but isn't looking right in IE 9, or any version of IE.  I am using an .eot font, but it seems that it is being ignored by IE (which according to documentation, it is supposed to work in IE browsers).
3. The CSS3 text-shadow property is not working, is there a way to get this effect for users with IE Browsers?

How can I fix, atleast, problems 1 and 2 with IE?  For Problem #1:  Should I use a table instead?  Is that the only way?

***EDIT***

I made the following changes to the code:

HTML:

```
<div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="image"><img class='header_img' src='images/image1.jpg' alt="" /></div>
    <div class="image"><img class='header_img' src='images/image2.jpg' alt="" /></div>
    <div class="image"><img class='header_img' src='images/image3.jpg' alt="" /></div>
    <div class="image"><img class='header_img' src='images/image4.jpg' alt="" /></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.image
{
    width: 25%;
}

.header_img
{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
}
```

Now this displays the images on top of one another instead of side by side:

IE:

[image: IE9 on top of one another]

ALL OTHER BROWSERS:

[image]

Comment: Try placing each image in a DIV and set the width of the DIV to be 25%. Then set the images with the DIVS to be "max-width: 100%". You shoudl also set "overflow: hidden" on the parent DIV which contains the new floating DIVs so as to clear the floats.

Comment: While this sounds great, this does not work.  After applying your changes, the images are not on top of one another instead of side by side.  I think it's because I have the images at 640 pixels wide each to compensate for bigger screen resolutions.  So how would I do this in that case?

Comment: @BillyMoat - Added the results of what you suggested to the bottom of the question so you can see for yourself what happened.

Comment: Here's a demo of what I'd suggested. Maybe you can use this to get yours working: http://jsfiddle.net/asa99/d

Comment: If I add `float:left` to the `div.image` css rule, it fixes it in all browsers, EXCEPT IE is still on top of each other... with a 640 pixel width on each image...

Comment: I have it set up EXACTLY the way you do now, and it is not working in IE.

Comment: @PolishPrince - I don't think a fiddle is better than REAL LIFE EXAMPLES!  I think jsfiddle tends to fix display problems on their end of things that can interfere with the display of the coding sometimes.

Comment: @SolomonClosson No need to throw all your code to make me scroll.

Comment: @PolishPrince - You're right, I can probably remove some of it.  It really isn't that much code though, so didn't think it would be a big deal.  I've seen people on here post files have have over 200 lines before.

Comment: So I guess there is no way to solve the width issue.  How about the @font-face css property issue? Anyone?

Comment: @BillyMoat OMG, I fixed the problem in IE 9 by adding in the `<!DOCTYPE html>` yayyyy!!!!  But now there is still the font problem!

Comment: I had assumed you would have had a valid doctype declared hence why I hadn't mentioned it. You must declare a valid doctype on all pages. You should be aware that the doctype you have added is the html5 doctype and although you aren;t uactually using any html5 elements in your current code you may do in the future so you should consider adding the html5 shim for <IE9 support. http://code.google.com/p/html5shim/ Also consider using a css reset file: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: please add your solution as the answer